# Adding the "%" to a variable

Tags: css, sass

I want to write this mixin:

```
@mixin top_a($sep-a: 2.5) {
padding-top: $sep-a + %;}
```

But unfortunately this throws in an error.
How do I add the percentage to the value correctly?

Comment: It looks like you want a variable, not a mixin

Comment: Interesting. I can get it to work with `px` as `#{$sep-a}px`, but if I replace `px` by `%` sass chokes.

Comment: @Thomas - it's not a good idea because `#{$sep-a}px` return string and `$sep-a * 1px` return value. Here you have [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8254941/1017941) of this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply multiply by `1%`?

```
padding-top: $sep-a * 1%;
```