# Sass @each pass variable to mixin

Tags: sass, bourbon, neat

I'm trying to create some BS-like classes for a grid, using Bourbon Neat grid mixins. My code looks like this:

```
@each $num in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 {
  .span#{$num} {
    @include span-columns(#{$num});
  }
}
```

What I want to happen is this:

```
.span1 {
  @include span-columns(1);
}

.span2 {
  @include span-columns(2);
}

//...
```

Grunt build log is saying:

```
Syntax error: Undefined operation: "1 times 4.2358em".
    on line 9 of bower_components/neat/app/assets/stylesheets/grid/_private.scss, in `span-columns'
    from line 25 of app/sass/main.scss
```

So what I can't figure out is why I can't pass the value from $num to the mixin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Math with interpolated variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254941/math-with-interpolated-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified example from the [docs](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while#for) to suit your case. And I used a `@for` loop in place of the `@each`, although you could do it with the `@each` as well. The Problem is that you pass the variable as a string, resulting in math operations on a string, you have to remove the `#{}` from the variable.

```
$class-slug: span !default;

@for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .#{$class-slug}#{$i} {
        @include span-column($i);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
[Play with this gist on SassMeister.](http://sassmeister.com/gist/ad6af70898402282e438)

Comment: Your suggestion is basically the same, so is the outcome.

Comment: No it is not. You passed the variable as a string, i.e. trying to perform a math function on a string. That is why your error says `Undefined operation: "1 times 4.2358em"`(note the quotation marks). Please check http://sassmeister.com/gist/ad6af70898402282e438

Comment: Oh, now I see. Makes perfect sense and works this way. Sorry for misreading that the first time.