# Manipulate function assigned variable value in SASS

Tags: css, function, sass

I'm dynamically assigning a value to a `$baseline` variable using SASS functions.

I have a px to REM converter

```
$old-ie: true;
$font-base: 16px;

@function rem($size) {

  @if ($old-ie) {
    @return #{$size}px;
  }

  @else {
    $remSize: $size / $font-base;
    @return #{$remSize}rem;
  }

}

$baseline = rem(10);

h1 {
  margin-bottom: $baseline*2;
  // This shows as margin-bottom: rem(10)*2; in the stylesheet if $old-ie is set to true.
}
```

Could be related to interpolation but the * 1px hack doesn't seem to solve it.
Any suggestions / alternatives or workarounds?

Comment: There needs to be enough code here to compile as is (undefined variables, etc.) *and* reproduce the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `rem(10*2)`?

Comment: @RaphaelDDL The multiplication happens to the variable, not the original function call. Updated the code.

Comment: @cimmanon This is not a duplicate, updated the code to better explain

Comment: You need to reread the other question then.  You're both trying to perform arithmetic operations on strings.  Funny how not performing arithmetic on strings makes it work, isn't it?  http://sassmeister.com/gist/7237a4f53d00ba30b785

Comment: Huh, I literally just tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Hmm... I tried that and it didn't solve the issue; it obviously works though so something else must be going on as well. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Better duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254941/math-with-interpolated-variables