# calculating variables-arrays with SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass, mixins

I'm using gulp to create sprites. Here is what i'm receiving at the one of the image

```
$s-ico-webdesign: '442px', '0px', '-442px', '0px', '60px', '60px', '538px', '519px', 'sprite.png';
```

It is array with data of the sprite image. I need to get a half of the height of the one sprite element. My mixin is:

```
@mixin sprite-top-half-margin($sprite) {
  $height: #{nth($sprite, 6)} / 2;
  margin-top : $height;
}
```

And finally my code is:

```
.add-nav .sub-menu .web-design a:before {
  @include sprite($s-ico-webdesign);
  @include sprite-top-half-margin($s-ico-webdesign);
  left:22px;
}
```

margin-top is not compiling. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Alternate duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254941/math-with-interpolated-variables

Comment: @cimmanon, how this question does duplicate "Adding a unit to a number"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a casting error in your code. `#{nth($sprite, 6)}` returns `string`. So  `Sass` can not do any math operations on it.

The answer is to use `string-to-number` parser. I have used the one here: [sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9fa19d254864f33d4a80), made by https://github.com/HugoGiraudel

I have made a gist for you with the solution: http://sassmeister.com/gist/b77a6f3b5ef798111c59

The most valuable part is:

```
@mixin sprite-top-half-margin($sprite) {
  $height: to-number(nth($sprite, 6)) / 2;
  margin-top : $height;
}
```

And the correct output:

```
.add-nav .sub-menu .web-design a:before {
  margin-top: 30px;
  left: 22px;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it was helped

Comment: I can't believe you're suggesting using a 3rd party library to solve this problem.

Comment: @cimmanon, yeaah, library of 40 lines.