# scss multiply em with number

Tags: css, sass

I cant find the answer on why is this bothering SCSS, i want to multiply something (number) with unit in "em" with a number without a unit, for example:

```
1.5em * 2
```

this returns an error *"Error: Undefined operation: "1.5em times 2"*".
I'm coming for LESS where this kind of multiplying is normal.

I was also having a problem with this kind of multiplication:

```
1.5 * 1em
```

Compiler was throwing the same error as above, but i fixed the problem with this:

```
1.5 + em
```

Is this solution good? Its passing through compiler but i cant apply the same fix for `1.5em * 2`

Comment: Cannot reproduce, please provide the actual code that reproduces the problem: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/c5f764f72c20728aff8e

Comment: @cimmanon
Ok whats going on, on sassmeister the bug is not there? i also cant reproduce the error. Im compiling with Koala.app with sass 3.4.9. which is few versions lower then on sassmeister

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254941/math-with-interpolated-variables

Comment: Both Ruby and LibSass version works... Do you use new version of a Sass compiler?

Comment: Adding your suggested code here http://www.sassmeister.com/ works fine? Any more details on your compiler - Grunt / Gulp npm pieces etc please.